# Local WebRTC signaling server

Tags: node.js, html, websocket, webrtc

I am using firebase signaling server for my webRTC website.

I am informed I can use websocket for implementation of my own local signaling server.

I tried the example on [Link](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/websocket-over-nodejs) and it works. When I replace my firebase code it doesn't work.

Firebase code

```
var config = {
            openSocket: function(config) {

                var channel = config.channel || location.href.replace(/\/|:|#|%|\.|\[|\]/g, '');
                var socket = new Firebase('https://webrtc.firebaseIO.com/' + channel); //EXTERNAL SERVER need change
                socket.channel = channel;
                socket.on("child_added", function(data) {
                    config.onmessage && config.onmessage(data.val());
                });
                socket.send = function(data) {
                    this.push(data);
                };
                config.onopen && setTimeout(config.onopen, 1);
                socket.onDisconnect().remove();
                return socket;

            },
```

Websocket over nodejs code

```
var channelName = location.href.replace(/\/|:|#|%|\.|\[|\]/g, ''); // using URL as room-name

            var SIGNALING_SERVER = 'ws://172.20.34.132:12034';
            connection.openSignalingChannel = function(config) {
                config.channel = config.channel || this.channel;
                var websocket = new WebSocket(SIGNALING_SERVER);
                websocket.channel = config.channel;
                websocket.onopen = function() {
                    websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
                        open: true,
                        channel: config.channel
                    }));
                    if (config.callback)
                        config.callback(websocket);
                };
                websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
                    config.onmessage(JSON.parse(event.data));
                };
                websocket.push = websocket.send;
                websocket.send = function(data) {
                    websocket.push(JSON.stringify({
                        data: data,
                        channel: config.channel
                    }));
                };
            }
```

Comment: What error are you exactly getting or where are you exactly getting stuck? Few details on that will be helpful.

Comment: with firebase signaling server the live stream work with websocket it does not work..

Comment: Isolate the problem. I recommend you debug the websocket connection separately, as this seems to have nothing to do with WebRTC.